# The electric Field inside PN junction in reverse bias

Tags: electric-fields, semiconductor-physics

In the unbiased PN junction the electric Field inside the depletion region is just due to the fixed charges inside it

But what happens in case of reverse
basing ?

[image]

In case of reverse bias the reverse electric Field due to the battery widen the depletion region which Create more charges in it and hence increase the field inside it

But after increasing the PN junction depletion region, does any point inside the depletion region sense just electric Field coming from the depletion region or additional to it the battery field ?

For an example: let us assume that the electric Field in reverse biased PN junction inside the depletion region after being widened equal to $E_{1}$ and the battery produce a constant electric Field equal to $E_{b}$
Then Does any point inside the depletion region equal to $E_{1}+E_{b}$ or just $E_{1}$ ? And why ?

Comment: How would you distinguish the applied from the built in field?

Answer (score 0):

The entire electric field in the depletion zone of a pn-diode can be considered to only be caused by the ionized dopant space charge density in the depletion zone(via Poisson equation). The only influence of the diode bias stems from the change of the width of the depletion zone, which increases with reverse bias. Only for very large forward bias, the space charge of the mobile carriers starts to influence the electric field.